# Need to maximize the excel window after opening it using win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, window

I am opening the excel sheet using `win32com.client` and bringing window to foreground using Activate function. But the window is opening in minmized view. I need to maximize it. Please help

```
 import win32com.client as win32

 excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
 wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\\blp\\1700.xlsx')
 wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\\blp\\Book1.xlsx')
 excel.Visible = True

 wb1.Activate()
```

Please let me know how to maximize the Excel window. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'Path...\YourFile.xlsx')
excel.Visible = 1
excel.WindowState = win32.constants.xlMaximized  # this works for me
```

Also when you prefix a string path with `r''` you do not need to escape the slashes.

**Update:**  If you want to see what COM constants are available then you need to use `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` once because it will generate a file which contains all the constants from a type library in an object called win32com.clients.constants. After you ran the above line of code then a folder is created in your operating system's temp directory. For example on Windows the temp directory is located at `C:\Users\'UserName'\AppData\Local\Temp`. There will be a folder in there named `gen_py`. On my system, the available constants you can use are found inside `gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\__init__.py`. Note that folder 3.7 is the current Python version that you are using so this may vary for you and the following folder that is named with numbers may also be different. After opening the `__init__.py` file the available constants are found inside the class named `constants`.

This is how I answered your qestion actually. The Excel Maximize option was in the class constants as `xlMaximized =-4137 # from enum XlWindowState`.

Also after the `gen_py` folder is created in the temp directory of your operating system you can use the constants with `win32.Dispatch or win32.DispatchEx` then but if the aforementioned folder doesn't exist yet then you must use `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` once to create it.

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing for Outlook? I've tried ```outlook.WindowState = win32.constants.olMaximized``` but it didn't work unfortunately